# Calculating entries in a transition probability matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$ on the state space $S=$ $\{1, \ldots, m+1\}, m \geq 1$, with transition probability matrix of dimension $(m+1) \times(m+1)$

$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac{1}{m} & \ldots & \frac{1}{m} \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Let $T_{i}(1)=\min \left\{n>0 \mid X_{n}=i\right\}$ be the first time in state $i$ after time zero. Show that

$p_{11}^{(2 n)}=1$ and $p_{11}^{(2 n+1)}=0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

I am really new to working with transition matrices. From my understanding the notation $p_{11}^{2n}$ is the probability of going from state $1$ to state $1$ in $2n$ steps which would be the first entry, i.e staying in the same first state. However, I have no idea on how I can calculate this for odd and even powers using the TPM, $P$. Would I have to proof it for odds and even powers using induction

Answer (score 1):

Computing $$P^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \frac1m & \ldots & \frac1m \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \frac1m & \ldots & \frac1m
\end{array}\right)\quad \text{and}\quad P^3 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac1m & \ldots & \frac1m \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0
\end{array}\right) = P$$

You can easily prove by induction that $P^{2n} = P^2$ and $P^{2n+1} = P$ which proves your claim easily.

Comment: I calculated the first even and odd power $2$ and $3$ - I am stuck after this as I am not sure exactly on how to apply induction when dealing with matrices.

Comment: Still can't get it to work.